# Can I edit plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter-dependencies

The problem I face is getting error in ***flutter plugin***, and I have no solution. So **I decide to edit some code in plugin**, Am I right or wrong for that solution?

Any idea please ?

Thanks.

Comment: of course, you can but first, can you give us more info about the error you face because it may be fixed without editing the plugin

Comment: @OmarSherif I'm using flutter_account_kit: ^0.7.0. After success verification by phone number, I can not get data from response. After I change some code in plugin, It's work.

Comment: but mind that your changes will get overwritten if you update the plugin so better solution would be either you fork the plugin and point the plugin in your project to that forked repo or you use that plugin locally as part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely you can modify plugin as you want unless and until you can not solve errors without changing it.

I also once change rating plugin to get desire ui in my code.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is Yes.

Yes, you can fork that repo, edit the code according to your requirements.

And then, you have two options

1) Raise the Pull Request and wait till it gets merged or
2) Directly use your updated plugin code

Here is the reference [link](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies) which will help you to use the updated plugin code as a dependancy.

Comment: @SournVisal if you think my answer solved the problem then you can mark it accept and help others to identify the correct answer from the given answers.